# How to find the number of positive integral points (points that are positive integers) that satisfy a given exponential function?

Tags: calculus

For example if I have an equation f(x) =1/(2^x -3), by intuition found for x=2 , f(x)=1 . Then If we plot the graph of f(x) we find that 2,1 lies on the graph of the function. When x>2, f(x) decreases and has an asymptotic y=0 . When x<2 the graph has vertical asymptotic x=ln(3)/ln(2). Now I'd we have an exponential function of this type with n variables like f(x1,x2...,xn-1) how can we find number of integral points lying on the graph.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Start by defining exactly what you mean by "an exponential function of this type having $n$ variables".